# Url parameters for Data Import Wizard

Tags: parameters, data-import-wizard

I'm wondering if it is possible to define URL parameters for the new Data Import wizard.

https://xxx.salesforce.com/dataImporter/dataimporter.app

Simply put I would like to pre-select a custom object, and pre-select the "Add new records" choice in the wizard, and provide it as a button on a page layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter is **objectSelection**

See https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eUs9AAE for an example

For custom objects, use the API name; eg, **CustObjName__c**

Comment: awesome, thanks!